# What statistical test do I need when measuring non-normal population data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean, population

I have 10 interval data points, measured at 10 different occasions. They are not normally distributed, and the data is the population, not the sample. I want to test whether the mean has increased from start to finish. I thought I should maybe use a paired t-test, but the normality assumption is violated.

Comment: If your data are the full population, not a sample, then there is nothing to test. The mean you calculate is the true population mean, not an estimate. Therefore, you can simply compare the means and note whether they have increased or not.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I was wondering this, but I want to state if the increase is significant. For instance, if the mean increased from 4.5 to 5 with a range from 0 to 10.

Comment: There is nothing to test.  Statistical significance isn't meaningful when you have the population, because you know the null is false.

Comment: See @PeterFlom's reply. [tag:statistical-significance] refers to the question how likely it is to see a large increase purely by chance, *because of sampling from the underlying distribution*. If you have the full population, there is no meaningful significance any more. (You might say that the $p$ value distribution degenerated to a discrete $\{0,1\}$ distribution.)

Comment: @roncook I agree with Stephan and Peter -- if you have the population of interest there's nothing to infer -- you can see if the null hypothesis is true with perfect information, just by looking. There's literally nothing to test beyond that. If the mean increased by *any amount whatever, no matter how trivial* that's statistically "significant"; all p-values are either exactly 0 or exactly 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Have entire population?

You can simply compute any statistic (mean, median, std, ...) to determine the difference. Then make a decision if that difference is practically significant which would depend on the domain.

### Have a sample and want to make an inference?

To get around the normality requirement you could use a pairwise [Wilcoxon signed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test). The observations are ordered and then the difference between the pairs is used to form the W statistic.

If you have more than one test to perform there are multiple comparison methods available. I know R has a wilcoxon pairwise function `pairwise.wilcox.test` in the `stats` package available in base R.

If those measurements at 10 different occasions are on the same experiment units (EUs) you may need to consider looking into repeated measurement analysis or perhaps spatial. There are techniques used to separate the error due to experiment unit differences. EU1 might like the taste of coffee while EU2 might not and thus inherently drinks less coffee. The differences could apply to objects as well; I don't want to give off the impression it applies to human EUs.

Comment: Thanks, the Wilcoxon test looks like what I need, but could you please explain what you mean by a 'round' of tests?

Comment: I simply mean you will need to do a pairwise comparison to test if the means are different. I added a snippet about pairwise Wilcoxon signed ranked test available in R. You can do more research here using the keywords `multiple comparison` as well.

Comment: @Glen_b Nope it doesn't make sense. I missed that the data was the entire population. I'll go ahead and delete my answer :D Which apparently I can't do. I'll make an edit instead....